# HierarchicalDataTemplate Bind only data that has a property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Tree View and want to bind the class that has the value IsFolder=true

I have tried setting the style with

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HideElement" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsFolder}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<TreeView Name="FolderTree" Grid.Column="0" SelectedItemChanged="FolderTree_SelectedItemChanged" >

    <TreeView.Resources>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource HideElement}"/>

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

but sadly this still creates a Listview Item

The node class

```cs
public class Node
{
        public Node()
        {
            Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        }
public bool IsFolder { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

I want it to display only the results that have IsFolder==true and I don't want to have invisible elements for thje ones that have IsFolder==false

Comment: Have you tried to filter with CollectionViewSource? https://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to bind to another filtered source?

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
    }
    public bool IsFolder { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Folders { get; set; }

    public void Add(Node node)
    {
        Nodes.Add(node);
        if (node.IsFolder)
            Folders.Add(node);
    }

    public void Remove(Node node)
    {
        Nodes.Remove(node);
        if (node.IsFolder)
            Folders.Remove(node);
    }
}
```

And then you bind to Folders instead of Nodes.

Comment: So if I delete an item fro Folders  will it get deleted from Nodes Aswell?

Comment: Then you can declare Folders as an `ObservableCollection` too. And whenever you delete a node from `Nodes` you check if it is a folder, if so, then you removed also from folders. This way you save a lot of problems IMO

Comment: @WPFmorelikeWTF I have edited the answer to show how this could be achieved. Obviously you can add more optimizations, and features... it is just demo code